# Kernel hangs when trying keyboard LED blinking module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, porting

I was searching for a simple Linux Kernel driver to demo talking to real world Hardware with the available interface on PC and came across a Keyboard LED programming. This program first seems to be published in [TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN1201) for older Kernels older than 2.6.36 which has been modified to work with new kernels at the below link. When I ran code from [here](http://tuxthink.blogspot.in/2013/02/kbledsc-for-linux-kernel-version-375.html), my system freezes.

I am using `Ubuntu 11.10` with Linux Kernel as `3.0.0.2-generic`. Any idea what could be causing the hang?

Comment: what `dmesg` shows after inserting?

Comment: I am not able to view demsg and it crashes immediately.

Comment: @pkumarn Try stubbing out everything so that it is a skeleton driver.  Then start un-commenting code that touches the hardware.  Try reading from the HW, then slowly converge on what causes it to hang.

Comment: @pkumarn Try to configure `kdump` and `crash` packages which will help  you to understand reason for Kernel panics. You can refer to [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe) for configuring `kdump`. Let us know `vmcore` and `dmesg` outputs.